# Creating a Node.js stream from two piped streams

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

I'd like to combine two Node.js streams into one by piping them, if possible. I'm using [Transform](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform) streams.

In other words, I'd like my library to return `myStream` for people to use. For example they could write:

```js
process.stdin.pipe(myStream).pipe(process.stdout);
```

And internally I'm using a third-party `vendorStream` that does some work, plugged into my own logic contained in `myInternalStream`. So what's above would translate to:

```js
process.stdin.pipe(vendorStream).pipe(myInternalStream).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Can I do something like that? I've tried `var myStream = vendorStream.pipe(myInternalStream)` but that obviously doesn't work.

To make an analogy with `bash`, let's say I want to write a program that checks if the letter `h` is present in the last line of some stream (`tail -n 1 | grep h`), I can create a shell script:

```bsh
# myscript.sh
tail -n 1 | grep h
```

And then if people do:

```bsh
$ printf "abc\ndef\nghi" | . myscript.sh
```

It just works.

This is what I have so far:

```js
// Combine a pipe of two streams into one stream

var util = require('util')
  , Transform = require('stream').Transform;

var chunks1 = [];
var stream1 = new Transform();
var soFar = '';
stream1._transform = function(chunk, encoding, done) {
  chunks1.push(chunk.toString());
  var pieces = (soFar + chunk).split('\n');
  soFar = pieces.pop();
  for (var i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
    var piece = pieces[i];
    this.push(piece);
  }
  return done();
};

var chunks2 = [];
var count = 0;
var stream2 = new Transform();
stream2._transform = function(chunk, encoding, done) {
  chunks2.push(chunk.toString());
  count = count + 1;
  this.push(count + ' ' + chunk.toString() + '\n');
  done();
};

var stdin = process.stdin;
var stdout = process.stdout;

process.on('exit', function () {
    console.error('chunks1: ' + JSON.stringify(chunks1));
    console.error('chunks2: ' + JSON.stringify(chunks2));
});
process.stdout.on('error', process.exit);


// stdin.pipe(stream1).pipe(stream2).pipe(stdout);

// $ (printf "abc\nd"; sleep 1; printf "ef\nghi\n") | node streams-combine.js
// Outputs:
// 1 abc
// 2 def
// 3 ghi
// chunks1: ["abc\nd","ef\nghi\n"]
// chunks2: ["abc","def","ghi"]

// Best working solution I could find
var stream3 = function(src) {
  return src.pipe(stream1).pipe(stream2);
};
stream3(stdin).pipe(stdout);

// $ (printf "abc\nd"; sleep 1; printf "ef\nghi\n") | node streams-combine.js
// Outputs:
// 1 abc
// 2 def
// 3 ghi
// chunks1: ["abc\nd","ef\nghi\n"]
// chunks2: ["abc","def","ghi"]
```

Is this at all possible? Let me know if what I'm trying to do isn't clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can watch for something to be piped to your stream, and then `unpipe` it and pipe it to the streams you're interested in:

```
var PassThrough = require('stream').PassThrough;

var stream3 = new PassThrough();

// When a source stream is piped to us, undo that pipe, and save
// off the source stream piped into our internally managed streams.
stream3.on('pipe', function(source) {
  source.unpipe(this);
  this.transformStream = source.pipe(stream1).pipe(stream2);
});

// When we're piped to another stream, instead pipe our internal
// transform stream to that destination.
stream3.pipe = function(destination, options) {
  return this.transformStream.pipe(destination, options);
};

stdin.pipe(stream3).pipe(stdout);
```

You can extract this functionality into your own constructable stream class:

```
var util = require('util');
var PassThrough = require('stream').PassThrough;

var StreamCombiner = function() {
  this.streams = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);

  this.on('pipe', function(source) {
    source.unpipe(this);
    for(i in this.streams) {
      source = source.pipe(this.streams[i]);
    }
    this.transformStream = source;
  });
};

util.inherits(StreamCombiner, PassThrough);

StreamCombiner.prototype.pipe = function(dest, options) {
  return this.transformStream.pipe(dest, options);
};

var stream3 = new StreamCombiner(stream1, stream2);
stdin.pipe(stream3).pipe(stdout);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @brandon, this is awesome! Updated my Gist https://gist.github.com/nicolashery/5910969

Comment: This is awesome. I was thinking about doing something similar but I just didn't have confidence i wasn't missing some subtlety that would make my solution wrong. Thanks for the confidence

Comment: FWIW, for this solution to work, you're required to pipe stream3 to a source (stdin in this case) before piping it to stdout. So, no stream3.pipe(stdout); stream3.write(data); But this is a great help! Thank you!

Comment: Turns out, stream3 is a transform stream, so it doesn't have a write method, anyway.

Comment: Won't this break when you pipe multiple streams into the same `StreamCombiner` object? I think `this.transformStream` should be created once in the constructor, not be overwritten on each `pipe` event.

Comment: Is there any library providing that functionality?

Answer (score 4):

One option is perhaps to use [multipipe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multipipe) which lets you chain multiple transforms together, wrapped as a single transform stream:

```
// my-stream.js
var multipipe = require('multipipe');

module.exports = function createMyStream() {
  return multipipe(vendorStream, myInternalStream);
};
```

Then you can do:

```
var createMyStream = require('./my-stream');

var myStream = createMyStream();

process.stdin.pipe(myStream).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Clarification: This makes stdin go through vendorStream, then myInternalStream and finally stdout.

Comment: You can apparently also use https://www.npmjs.com/package/lazypipe with a slightly different api

Answer (score 0):

There's now a built-in function called [`stream.compose`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streamcomposestreams) to achieve this: (currently marked as Stability 1: experimental, though it has been in node.js since version 16.9.0)

```js
const stream = require('stream');
const myStream = stream.compose(vendorStream, myInternalStream);
process.stdin.pipe(myStream).pipe(process.stdout);
```

> Combines two or more streams into a Duplex stream that writes to the first stream and reads from the last. [...]
>
> Because stream.compose returns a new stream that in turn can (and should) be piped into other streams, it enables composition. In contrast, when passing streams to stream.pipeline, typically the first stream is a readable stream and the last a writable stream, forming a closed circuit.